# Is there a way to groupby multiple columns under a single column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a table like this ---

| AREA | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dhaka | [1,2,3] | [2,3] | [4,5,6] |
| Sylhet | [10,11] | [7,9,10] | [10,13,7] |

I want this table in this shape--

| Area | total_num |
| --- | --- |
| Dhaka | 1 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 3 |
|  | 4 |
|  | 5 |
|  | 6 |
| Sylhet | 10 |
|  | 11 |
|  | 7 |
|  | 9 |
|  | 13 |

how can I do it in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

If necessary convert values to lists:

```
import ast

df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].applymap(ast.literal_eval)
```

And then reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), explode lists by [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), creare 2 columns DataFrame and last remove duplicates:

```
df = (df.set_index('AREA')
        .stack()
        .explode()
        .droplevel(1)
        .reset_index(name='total_num')
        .drop_duplicates())
print (df)
      AREA total_num
0    Dhaka         1
1    Dhaka         2
2    Dhaka         3
5    Dhaka         4
6    Dhaka         5
7    Dhaka         6
8   Sylhet        10
9   Sylhet        11
10  Sylhet         7
11  Sylhet         9
14  Sylhet        13
```